# "Revolve" through selected rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
| ID | game | player | their_turn |
===================================
| 1  | 1    | 1      | 0          |
-----------------------------------
| 2  | 1    | 2      | 1          |
-----------------------------------
| 3  | 1    | 3      | 0          |
-----------------------------------
| 4  | 1    | 4      | 0          |
-----------------------------------
| 5  | 1    | 5      | 0          |
```

My goal is to select, ordered by ID and for a specific game, the player immediately after the one where their_turn is 1, looping back to the lowest/first ID when it reaches the max ID.

Example, if it's currently player 2's turn like it is now, I want it to select player 3. If it's player 5's turn, I want it to select player 1. And when it's player 1, it'll select player 2.

I can always do some processing with this in PHP after selecting all the rows, but I was wondering how I would go about doing this right in MySQL.

### Update: New table structure

I've ended up restructuring my table; their_turn is now moved to a separate table (non-relevant columns excluded):

```
Players          Rounds
| ID | game |    | ID | game | player |
=============    ======================
| 1  | 1    |    | 1  | 1    | 1      |
| 2  | 1    |    | 2  | 1    | 2      |
| 3  | 1    |
| 4  | 1    |
| 5  | 1    |
```

So, same goal; selecting the next player in line; either the one who's ID is either greater than that of the player for the latest round for the game, or, failing that, the lowest player ID for that game. I've never worked with IF statements in MySQL, which I imagine are what's necessary, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about it.

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: data structure is a little confusing.  What is the difference between player and id?  Can one player have more than one ID?  Or does the player field hold the sequence for a particular game?  Can we count on the player field containing consecutive integers for a particular game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** Here is a query for the changed table schema

```
SELECT CASE WHEN player + 1 > max_id 
            THEN min_id
            ELSE player + 1
       END next_player
  FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(id) max_id, MIN(id) min_id
    FROM players
   WHERE game = 1
) p CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT player 
    FROM rounds
   WHERE game = 1
   ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1
) r
```

Output:

```
| NEXT_PLAYER |
---------------
|           3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf3a2/2)** demo

**ON a side note:** *Please stop changing your question. If you changed your table schema or made other drastic changes evaluate and appreciate answers to your original question and post a new one.*

**An answer to the original question:**
A possible solution when ids are not guaranteed to be contiguous

```
(
  SELECT *
    FROM Table1
   WHERE game = 1
   ORDER BY id
   LIMIT 1
)
 UNION ALL
(
  SELECT *
    FROM Table1
   WHERE game = 1
     AND ID > 
   (
     SELECT MIN(id) 
       FROM Table1 
      WHERE game = 1 
        AND their_turn = 1
   )
   ORDER BY id
   LIMIT 1
)
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

If ids are always contiguous for a game then you can do

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM Table1 t 
 WHERE id = 
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(id * their_turn) + 1 > MAX(id) 
              THEN MIN(id) 
              ELSE MAX(id * their_turn) + 1 END next_id
    FROM Table1
   WHERE game = 1
)
```

Output in both cases based on your sample data is:

```
| ID | GAME | PLAYER | THEIR_TURN |
-----------------------------------
|  3 |    1 |      3 |          0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc6df/18)** demo for both queries.

Comment: I ended up restructuring my tables (see update section) to a slightly more logical setup, so unfortunately your solution won't work.

Comment: See updated answer. If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Answer (score 0):

General algorithm:

- Find the position of the player that has their_turn=1 (hint: you need to create a rank in order to determine the actual position)
- select position from step 1 + 1 modulo total number of players